# Redondear 2 esquinas de rectángulo con fpdf - php

Tags: php, fpdf

Necesito saber si es posible redondear solamente dos esquinas de un rectángulo en fpdf, he estado investigando y no he podido encontrar la manera de hacerlo. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$pdf->RoundedRect(10, 230, 15, 15, 3, '0.5', 'DF');
```

Y lo que necesito es redondear solo 2 esquinas. No se si esto sería posible, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función RoundedRect tiene un parámetro $corners que permite hacer esto. Es un string con valores 1, 2, 3 o 4, donde:

1 = arriba izquierda

2 = arriba derecha

3 = abajo derecha

4 = abajo izquierda

Puedes combinarlos. Por ejemplo:

```
$pdf->RoundedRect($x, $y, $ancho, $alto, $radio, '13', 'DF');
```

creará un rectángulo con las esquinas superior izquierda e inferior derecha redondeadas

Comment: ¿Dónde está aplicando el parámetro `$corners` con esas propiedades?

Comment: El parámetro $corners es el que en el ejemplo he puesto como '13', indicando las esquinas 1 y 3. Te dejo la dirección del manual de fpdf en donde lo explica [enlace](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script35.php)

Comment: Ya me funcionó, muchas gracias.